# Is it possible to send email via Google API with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-api

I have a simple page with a feedback form. The page should send email to me after submitting the form. I don't want to use any backend technology.

Is it possible to send email from the my own HTML page using the google API?

Or, for example, using the forms API, just submit the values from my own form.

Comment: no, however in this case you can open default mail client on user machine. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail

Comment: @virendrao do you still think the same way?

Comment: @virendrao please don't ignore me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Step-by-Step Example of using an HTML Form to send a "Contact Us" Message via Email without a Backend Server using a Google Script - No PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, Node.js etc.

https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server